# Logout function not working React-Native to Ruby on Rails? I can't delete the session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, authentication, react-redux

I am having trouble with my authentication actions from react-native to my ruby on rails backend api. I thought my signup/ sign in actions were working fine until I made my logout action and I began receiving a rails controller error.  My logout function, requests a delete of user's session and can't find it, but my login/signup functions have no problem creating a session.

My Sessions#Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  @user = User.find_by_credentials(
    params[:user][:username],
    params[:user][:password]
  )

  if @user
    login(@user)
    render "users/show.json.jbuilder"
  else
    render json: ["Invalid username/password combination"], status: 401
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = current_user   # I believe the problem is here, as it can't find current_user see 
                         # application controller below
  if @user
    logout
    render json: {}
  else
    render json: ["Nobody signed in"], status: 404
  end
end
end
```

Application#controller , where I find the current user based on the session_token

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :logout

  # private

  def current_user
    return nil unless session[:session_token]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(session_token: session[:session_token])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def login(user)
    user.reset_session_token!
    session[:session_token] = user.session_token
    @current_user = user
  end

  def logout
    current_user.reset_session_token!
    session[:session_token] = nil
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

My logout action:

```
export const testLogout = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(loadSpinner());
  axios({
    method: 'delete',
    url: 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/session',
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("response: ", response);
    if(reponse.status === 200) {
      {dispatch(logoutCurrentUser(response))}
    } else {
      console.log("status", response.status);
    };
  });
};
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: [:create, :show]
  resource :session, only: [:create, :destroy, :show]
end
```

The errors (1): 
Started DELETE "/session" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-05-27 10:23:23 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Completed 404 Not Found in 0ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms).

(2):
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Request failed with status code 404

Error 2 from the testLogout() function never even makes it to the .then(response) in the function.

Now this 404 error is my own from the #destroy method in my sessions_controller and I am a bit unsure how to get a better error here but from what I am reading online is that react-native handles browser cookies differently and I am concerned I am missing something conceptually but I am very unsure of what it is.  I know I could use AsyncStorage for persisting sessions but how does that factor in with the back-end rails authentication? Any help figuring out how to log out a user is greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using some form of a JWT for authentication handling. Using sessions with an external client is certainly possible, but it's a headache you probably don't want to deal with. Read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). In short, you don't want to deal with CORS if you don't have to.

This seems like a fairly decent guide if you're using devise: https://medium.com/@eth3rnit3/crud-react-native-ror-backend-with-devise-auth-token-4407cac3aa0b

Comment: I tried to use his guide but when i emailed me about the whereabouts of the code it turns out he deleted them so his links to the examples are gone.